# tensorflow 1.13.1 doesn't detect gpu

Tags: ubuntu, tensorflow, nvidia

I have been struggling with this for a while and read all the posts I found. I have gtx 1080 gpu on Ubuntu 16.04. My requirement is tensorflow 1.13.1. In my conda env I l have

```
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                        main  
_tflow_select             2.1.0                       gpu  
absl-py                   0.7.1                    py36_0    conda-forge
astor                     0.7.1                      py_0    conda-forge
c-ares                    1.15.0            h516909a_1001    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2019.6.16            hecc5488_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2019.6.16                py36_1    conda-forge
cudatoolkit               10.0.130                      0  
cudnn                     7.6.0                cuda10.0_0  
gast                      0.2.2                      py_0    conda-forge
grpcio                    1.16.1           py36hf8bcb03_1  
h5py                      2.9.0           nompi_py36hf008753_1102    conda-forge
hdf5                      1.10.4          nompi_h3c11f04_1106    conda-forge
keras-applications        1.0.7                      py_1    conda-forge
keras-preprocessing       1.0.9                      py_1    conda-forge
libblas                   3.8.0               10_openblas    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.8.0               10_openblas    conda-forge
libffi                    3.2.1             he1b5a44_1006    conda-forge
libgcc-ng                 9.1.0                hdf63c60_0  
libgfortran-ng            7.3.0                hdf63c60_0  
liblapack                 3.8.0               10_openblas    conda-forge
libopenblas               0.3.6                h6e990d7_5    conda-forge
libprotobuf               3.9.0                h8b12597_0    conda-forge
libstdcxx-ng              9.1.0                hdf63c60_0  
markdown                  3.1.1                      py_0    conda-forge
mock                      3.0.5                    py36_0    conda-forge
ncurses                   6.1               hf484d3e_1002    conda-forge
numpy                     1.16.4           py36h95a1406_0    conda-forge
openblas                  0.3.6                h6e990d7_5    conda-forge
openssl                   1.1.1c               h516909a_0    conda-forge
pip                       19.2.1                   py36_0    conda-forge
protobuf                  3.9.0            py36he1b5a44_0    conda-forge
python                    3.6.7             h357f687_1005    conda-forge
readline                  8.0                  hf8c457e_0    conda-forge
scipy                     1.3.0            py36h921218d_0    conda-forge
setuptools                41.0.1                   py36_0    conda-forge
six                       1.12.0                py36_1000    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.29.0               hcee41ef_0    conda-forge
tensorboard               1.13.1                   py36_0    conda-forge
tensorflow                1.13.1                   py36_0    conda-forge
tensorflow-estimator      1.13.0                     py_0  
tensorflow-gpu            1.13.1               h0d30ee6_0  
termcolor                 1.1.0                      py_2    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.9             hed695b0_1002    conda-forge
werkzeug                  0.15.5                     py_0    conda-forge
wheel                     0.33.4                   py36_0    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.4             h14c3975_1001    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.11            h516909a_1005    conda-forge
```

AFAIK, all the required software is there and are the right versions, cudnn, cuda-toolkit, tensorflow-gpu. But still tensorflow does not detect gpu. device_lib.list_local_devices() only reports CPU.

Anyone can suggest what else can be wrong?

Comment: Do you have a proper GPU driver installed? Conda doesn't do that for you.

Comment: yes. NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  418.67

Answer (score 1):

The issue is a bug in the Anaconda metadata for tensorflow 1.13. It can be fixed by also installing `tensorflow=*=*gpu*`.

This is only necessary for tensorflow 1.13.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with tensorflow 1.13.1, I was able to run it on GPU by uninstalling the `tensorflow` and installing the `tensorflow-gpu` again with **pip**

so:

`pip uninstall tensorflow`

`pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.13.1`

Comment: I am afraid it made no difference.

Comment: my set up works up to tensorflow-gpu 1.12.0. This must be some version discrepancy when using 1.13.1, but everything checks out on the compliance table.

Comment: So, you have used conda for installing cudatoolkit and cudnn ? Also the driver should be 410.x