# google colab cannot connect to gpu even i changed the runtime type

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, conv-neural-network

am using google colab ,tensorflow 1.13.1 and keras 2.2.4 to train Unet CNN model, i changed the accelerator to GPU via runtime/change runtime type then when am checking  if GPU used via the above line of code it shows that no GPU used, how can i fix this.

```
[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XNRC.png
```

Comment: how do you check whether GPU is used ? Please add your code

Comment: to check whether GPU used or not i run this line of code tf.test.gpu_device_name() and i got this output ' '

Comment: I can not see your output. Please add in text format

Comment: @Andrey this is the output: ' '

Comment: @Andrey the output is two quotes: ' '

Comment: have a look on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57277481/tensorflow-1-13-1-doesnt-detect-gpu